# Can I pipe a "tail -f " with mixed data containg JSONs to jq to visualize JSONs?

Tags: bash, logging, jq

I´ve playing for a whilen and resarching but I´m not able to find a solution.
I have some huge logs, where sometimes there are also huge JSONS. But to simplify imagine the following:

```
mkdir logs
cd logs/
echo "$(date) [INFO] something" >> huge_log.log
echo "$(date) [INFO] something more" >> huge_log.log
echo "$(date) [INFO] Something with json: {\"foo\": \"bar\"}" >> huge_log.log
tail -n 5 -f huge_log.log | how_to_filter? | jq '.'
```

Is it possible to be able to see something like this (the json as the output of jq '.' would be):

```
Tue Aug 18 12:42:24 CEST 2020 [INFO] something
Tue Aug 18 12:42:29 CEST 2020 [INFO] something more
Tue Aug 18 12:43:05 CEST 2020 [INFO] Something with json: 
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

So, somehow, automatically detect the jsons while printing the log and show them as the output would
be for:

```
echo "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" | jq '.'
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked for your example and seems reasonable to me. I'm iterating over every line in the logfile and if a line is matching the regex "{.*}" it's identifed as a json object and then formatted with jq. If the regex doesn't match however it prints out normal. I tested it, it works actually really well also for bigger more complex file.

```
tail -n 15 huge_log.log | while read line ; do if echo $line | egrep "\{.*}" >/dev/null;json=$(echo $line | egrep -oh "\{.*}" | jq '.');then echo $line | awk -v json="$json" -F "\{.*}" '{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n",$1,json,$2}'; fi;  done
```

Comment: I have tried it and more or less works, but it removes the content before and after the json.

Comment: @nck I edited my answer and it's doing what you want know. I'm keeping the part before and after json using awk now. If you want to change the formatting just tweak aroung with "printf". Now formatting is like: $beforejson \n $json \n $afterjson